# invariant violation webview has been removed from react native

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react-native application. When I run It it leaves me an error saying invariant violation webview has been removed from react-native even though I have not used web view in any single component or file. To make sure that I put a keyword search in my vscode editor but I was unable to find any single instance that I have used Web View.

These are my dependencies and dev-dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "formik": "^2.0.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-logic": "^2.1.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "yup": "^0.28.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
```

I tried to lot to find a solution for this problem on the internet. Then I found a similar question in the stackoverflow that questions gives answers for If I am using WebView so How can I solve this issue If I am not using WebView in any single component. Can Someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: You had dependency for  "react-native-webview": "^8.0.2", in an application

Comment: I see ```react-native-webview``` in your dependencies. Do you use it?

Comment: @B.Mohammad I install it after getting this error by solutions found on the internet.I am not using It.

Comment: Give a look to this post: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/818, it might be ```react-native-gesture-handler``` who causes your issue